# Mesos slaves deactivating

Tags: mesos, marathon

I have three machines setup. Each Machine has Zookeeper, Mesos master and slave, and Marathon.

I am attempting to use Marathon to start a simple rails application follow [this](http://mesosphere.io/learn/run-ruby-on-rails-on-mesos/#step-4) tutorial.

Whenever I try and create the task, the two mesos slaves that are not running on the same machine as the current mesos master,get deactivated for seemingly no reason.

The logs don't appear to be of any help. They just tell me that the slaves to deactivated, not why.

[here](https://gist.github.com/ankhers/9115659) is a gist with the mesos-master and the three slaves logs.

If you would like to see any additional information, please ask and I will get it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the fix to this, but I rebooted each of the three machines and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Justin, the gist is no longer there so I'm only speculating.

It wasn't the reboot but rather cleaning the mesos-slave work_dir that helped solve your issue. When slaves deactivate after startup, they log a line about this in slave logs, usually asking you to remove the `$WORK_DIR/meta` directory (which by default is under `/tmp/mesos/` and thus cleaned at reboot.